# Reading outlook and writing to excel using Python

Tags: python, outlook

i need to read all email from a particular address and get "some content" into excel

i have had some success in reading emails but i am stuck to get the content of these emails in to excel

```
import win32com.client
import xlsxwriter
import pandas
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Planned_power_outage.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders
folder = outlook(1)
inbox = folder.Folders("Inbox")
messages = inbox.Items
for message in messages:
if (message.SenderEmailAddress) == 'addess here':
       sent_date = message.senton.date()
       sender = message.Sender
       subject = message.Subject
       content = message.body 
       possible_node = subject.split(" ")[1]
              print(sender,subject,content)

i expect to see the output as below in a excel file

SENDER  SUBJECT                 CONTENT
alpha   this is subject0    blahbalahblahablah
alpha   this is subject1    blahbalahblahablah
alpha   this is subject2    blahbalahblahablah
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Specifically, what do "some success" and "I am stuck" mean? Please read [ask]. Are you asking how to write data to your workbook using `xlsxwriter`?

Comment: hi chris, i am new bee here and in fact to programming, yes am wanting to write the data from outlook in to Excel i am not sure if Xlsxwriter is the only option, once i have the data in excel i need python to find a particular group of words from the content and then do some thing else.. this is a big project and i am stuck at the very initial stage, any help is most appriciated

Comment: Okay, so you've already started. You've got a workbook and a worksheet. How did you know how to do that?

Comment: i think i cracked the code, i am now reading all emails from a particular address, extracting a particular word from the subject, copying the recceived_date,sender_deatils,subject,required field from subject and the content in to an excel.

Comment: i am now trying to do some regex on the content